# searchd has 2 processes when it should be one

Tags: centos, sphinx

My server is running searchd (Sphinx Search) in TWO processes but can't understand the reason why. Before it used to be one. What has changed recently is that I have introduced Delta indexing to the Sphinx.Conf which has been working fine from what I can tell. I have a cron merging in delta indexes to the main indexes as you'd expect.

Did the introduction of delta indexing create this new process instance?

If it helps, when I sudo searchd the processes are made one after another, which removes the possibility that it gets created later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 is normal. One is the actual process serving requests, the other is a watchdog. It sole purpose is if the main process dies, its automatically respawned. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-watchdog

There may also be more processes, when activly serving requests. Depending on exact settings, more processes may startup just for request.

Comment: Right, so my watchdog is clearly running as normal then but I still seems to get issues with the searchd daemon as it automatically turns off for unexplained reasons. From what I've just read about the watchdog, it should be triggering the daemon back on... ?